# What is the SVD of $ab^T + ba^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

What is the SVD of $A = ab^T + ba^T$ when a and b are column vectors? It is also given that $a^Tb = 0$.

I've tried finding $AA^T$ and $A^TA$ to find the e-values and e-vectors for $U$ and $\Sigma$ to no avail. This method worked for finding the SVD of $A = ab^T$, but no luck with this case. Any pointers to the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I saw this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472393/what-is-the-svd-of-abtbat), but I didn't quite get how they got the n-2 dimension null space. Moreover, it was confusing to me when they jumped from $(\alpha a+\beta b)=\lambda(\alpha a+\beta b)$ to the next equation, as I have no clue where they got ||a|| and ||b|| from.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the SVD of $ab^T+ba^T$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472393/what-is-the-svd-of-abtbat)

Comment: It should be added that in dimensions $2$, resp. $3$, this matrix is the symmetric matrix associated with the degenerated conic, resp. quadric made of a pair of orthogonal lines, resp. planes.

Comment: It's funny that the reference I have found has exactly the same title as yours...

Comment: Yes I saw that post before I asked my question. Their answer didn't make much sense to me hence why I thought to ask again. Especially at the "some transformations of this equation" part. Moreover, I didn't quite get how they got the n-2 dimension null space.

Comment: In this case, maybe you should have mentionned this reference into your question.

Comment: I just edited my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, I just realized that the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1472393) referenced in your question was about the *eigen-decomposition* of $ab^T+b^Ta$, not about its *Singular Values Decomposition (SVD)*. Therefore, I have chosen to postpone the answer to your questions to an Appendix.

Here is a simple way to address the SVD issue.

Let us consider for the sake of simplicity the case of dimension $3$ (the general case being a straightforward extension of this one).

Setting $$A=\frac{1}{\|a\|}a, B=\frac{1}{\|b\|}b,$$

one can obtain at once the SVD:

$$ab^t+ba^t=\|a\|\|b\|(AB^T+B^TA)$$

$$ab^t+ba^t=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}|&|&|\\A&B&W\\|&|&| \end{pmatrix}}_U\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}\|a\|\|b\|&0&0\\0&\|a\|\|b\|&0\\0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}}_{\Sigma}\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}-&B^T&-\\-&A^T&-\\-&W^T&- \end{pmatrix}}_{V^T}$$

where vector $W$ is completing $A,B$ into an ortho-normalized basis for $\mathbb{R^3}$.

In particular, we have a double non-zero singular value $\|a\|\|b\|$ (product of norms).

**Appendix:**

**First question** about the $n-2$ dimensions of the nullspace:

By (orthogonal) basis extension theorem one can add to $a,b$,  $n-2$ vectors $v_1,v_2,... v_{n-2}$ that constitute an orthogonal basis of $\mathbb{R^n}$. Then,

$$(ab^T+ba^T)v_k=a(b^Tv_k)+b(a^Tv_k)=a0+b0=0,$$

establishing that the kernel contains all the $v_k$s, therefore has dimension $\ge (n-2)$. As the dimension of the range is at least $2$ (it contains $a,b$), we deduce, using the rank-nullity theorem that the dimension of the kernel is exactly $(n-2)$ and the dimension of the range is $2$.

**Second question:**

$$(\alpha a+\beta b)=\lambda(\alpha a+\beta b)$$

$$(ab^T+ba^T)(\alpha a+\beta b)=\lambda(\alpha a+\beta b)$$

$$\alpha a\underbrace{(b^Ta)}_0+\beta a\underbrace{(b^Tb)}_{\|b\|^2}+\alpha b\underbrace{(a^Ta)}_{\|a\|^2}+\beta b\underbrace{(a^Tb)}_0=\lambda \alpha a+ \lambda \beta b$$

It remains to identify the coefficients of vectors $a$ and $b$.

**A side remark:** I had been working on the eigenvalues of a matrix of this form $ab^T+ba^T$ in a very interesting issue about average values of "products of dot products": see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2278978).

Comment: When you mention Z as the null vector, shouldn't the U matrix include Z?

Comment: I don't need $Z$ in fact.

Comment: I've been trying to parse your answer for a while but I'm still a bit confused. How did you know that ||a|| and ||b|| will be the 2 nonzero e-values and its corresponding e-vectors are A ($\frac{a}{||a||}$)  and B ($\frac{b}{||b||}$). How did you get $ab^T + ba^t = ||a|| ||b|| (AB^T + B^TA)$?

Comment: 1) It is the product $\|a\| \|b\|$ which is a singular value (not eigenvalue) ; I know it is a singular value because it is in the diagonal of $\Sigma$. 2) Yes, the corresponding left and right singular vectors (not eigenvectors) are resp. $A$ and $B$ . 3) Do you agree that $a=\|a\| A$ and $b=\|b\|B$. If I plug these expressions in $ab^T+ba^T$, I get $\|a\| A(\|b\|B)^T+(\|b\|B)^T\|a\| A=\|a\| \|b\|AB^T+\|a\| \|b\|B^TA=\|a\| \|b\|(AB^T+B^TA)$

Comment: That makes so much sense. And yes I meant singular value(or $\sqrt{\lambda}$) and the singular vector. Thank you so much for your time and in depth answer. I really do appreciate it! It's very clear now! :)